# Background for <li> tag

Tags: html-lists

I want to put a background image or background color for

tag but i dont know how to it. Thanks

```
    </div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
    <!---start-content---->
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-boxs">
                <div class="clear"> </div>
                <div class="type-videos">
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Korean Drama</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/qd60qa1L/1/

Basically you just need css for your html tag or a class.

html:

```
<!-- with css tag -->

<li>
  test2
</li>

<!-- or with css class -->

<li class="list">
  test3
</li>
```

css:

```
li {
  background-color:red;
}

/* with class*/

.list{
  background-color:green;
}
```